# Cannot open MongoDB Compass 1.19.3

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, mongodb

I recently updated MongoDB Compass to 1.19.3 from 1.16 on my system(Ubuntu 14.04 LTS)and now it does not open. Every time I launch the compass the window screen of the compass crashes and I cannot proceed. I tried reinstalling but it gives the same result. The previous version 1.16 was working fine but this problem started after the update. Can anyone guide me as to how to fix this issue? 
Also, can anyone post the link to download MongoDB Compass 1.16

[image: screenshot when MongoDb compass is started]

Comment: Can you see anything in /var/log/messages when you try to start it? Try setting up `tail -f /var/log/messages` in a terminal and then start the application. If something shows up in the logs, add it to your question (**as text, not as an image, please**)